# Corona Build for iOS with fake Code Signing Identity

Tags: ios, sdk, coronasdk

I'm trying to build an app for iOS with Corona SDK but I'm not going to release it for the AppStore it's just for personal use (My iDevice is jailbroken). That's why I'd rather not buy the apple license. Is there a way to install a fake Mobile Provisioning Profile that Corona recognizes? I already tried using JailCoder, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

I think corona checks the entire chain for validity so it would be hard to fake it anyway.